# Write a query to display max score along with exam type and name in MongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "56d5f7eb604eb380b0d8d8ce",
  },
  "student_id": 0,
  "scores": [
    {
      "type": "exam",
      "score": 78.40446309504266,
    },
    {
      "type": "quiz",
      "score": 73.36224783231339,
    },
    {
      "type": "homework",
      "score": 46.980982486720535,
    },
    {
      "type": "homework",
      "score": 76.67556138656222,
    },
  ],
  "class_id": 339,
}
```

the above is the sample doc. I want to find the maximum score along with its exam type name and I'm struggling to do it in MongoDB compass. following is the picture of MongoDB compass where I'm aggregating to get the max score.

[Screenshoot of MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fddfg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a sort and limit stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$match": { "score": { "$exists": true } } },
    {"$sort": { "score": -1 } },
    {"$limit": 1 },
])
```